# what is the difference between Hill climbing and A*?

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence, a-star, hill-climbing

In Artificial intelligence, these algprithms are very popular. I tried looking for methods to solve the 8puzzle problem and it seems like both of them have a similar approach. Can anyone explain what is the difference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Algorithms like weighted A* (Pohl 1970) systematically explore the
>   search space in ’best’ first order. ’Best’ is defined by a node
>   ranking function which typically considers the cost of arriving at a
>   node, g, as well as the estimated cost of reaching a goal from a node,
>   h. Some algorithms, such as A∗ ǫ (Pearl and Kim 1982) also consider
>   the distance of a node from the goal, d. Hill-climbing algorithms are
>   less deliberative; rather than considering all open nodes, they expand
>   the most promising descendant of the most recently expanded node until
>   they encounter a solution.

[Source (page 1, Introduction)](http://www.cs.unh.edu/~ruml/papers/beam-socs10.pdf)